# Getting COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE with SQLPro for MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to get the COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE using

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
FROM dbo.[CORDELACIUTAT Resource Time Registr_]
```

But I got this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1. 
>   Invalid column name 'COLUMN_NAME'. 
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1. 
>   Invalid column name 'DATA_TYPE'. (Line 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should query `information_schema.columns` view

```
select column_name, data_type 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'CORDELACIUTAT Resource Time Registr_'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't access that data directly from the table.
Try this:

```
select COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME =[CORDELACIUTAT Resource Time Registr_]
```